# I want to know what the middle notification symbol means please. the one That looks like a sheild with lines in it

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

I want to know what the symbol inn the middle means..the one with the lines:

[image: screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click image to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: I'm more curious to know where you're seeing this screen...

Comment: You could have used google image search.

Answer (score 0):

It's the logo for **Lookout** .

Found it [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-sa/cloud-platform/microsoft-intune-partners).

Hope this helped.

Comment: Aw, 5 seconds late :(

Comment: That's six :D @AndyYan .

Comment: Thank you!!  there is another one but I can't find a picture of it.  It's a white bubble with black in it.  Almost looks like a messenger bubble.

Comment: @Lapdn Please accept the answer you deem useful, it completes the process and gives both you and the corresponding author a little renown boost :)

Comment: Arghhhh ... Stack needs an auto update  feature to stop the falsely labeled unanswered questions !

Comment: @NoobFood They also need a feature to stop bumping such questions to the top, especially some *really* old ones (I mean, who still cares about Android 2.x problems today?).

Comment: True that @AndyYan .

Comment: Let's agree to agree

Answer (score 0):

It's the icon of [Lookout Security & Antivirus](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lookout).

[image]